# Adding Instagram filters on images in my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using [CSSGram](http://una.im/CSSgram/) on my website to make images have Instagram-like filters.
This is the method below to add a filter to a image:

```
 <figure class="aden">
 <img src="../img.png">
 </figure>
```

How can i add this effect to all the images in the webpage, instead of using `<figure class="">` before every single image, and also in a css section for  many images.

Can this be done using `javascript` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes apply to the container and style with css, example below:-

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(0.9) contrast(1.4) hue-rotate(150deg) invert(0.1);
```

Comment: Just read the last part, you can style just using figure as an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery  like

```
$('img').addClass('aden');
```

to add the css to all imgs

Comment: What did you try exactle @Zack? please look at the docs here https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Answer (score 0):

with JQUERY:

use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method

```
$('figure').addClass('aden')
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v356t2yz/)

or you can use just javascript:

```
var a = document.querySelector('figure');
if (a.classList) {
    a.classList.add('aden');
} else {
    a.className += ' aden';
}
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6whmfzso/)

Comment: i dont wont to use the <figure> tag, i want to use it for all the images in the website.

Answer (score 0):

The styles are based on a `img` sitting inside `figure` element. You could automatically wrap all of the images in a figure element like so

```
$(function() {
    $("img").wrap("<figure class='aden'></figure>");
});
```

However, you might want to be more specific with that selector as it could break other images like logos, social icons etc

Working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/cs9asjhs/

Comment: Updated with fiddle example. Make sure the code is running once the document is ready, like the example above.

Comment: thank you. do you have any idea how to make it work with tumblr photsets ?

Comment: It would entirely depend on the theme being used, sorry.